# How to fetch specific items from webservice

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hello I am pretty new to react native i am fetching some data from the webservice the data returned is around 1000 items and is printed to the console/terminal i need only two specific items to be printed on the console how do i do that

```html
import React from "react";
import {StyleSheet,View,ActivityIndicator,FlatList,Text,TouchableOpacity} from "react-native";

export default class Source extends React.Component {
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
return {
  title: "Source Listing",
  headerStyle: {backgroundColor: "#fff"},
  headerTitleStyle: {textAlign: "center",flex: 1}
 };
};
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
   loading: false,
   items:[]
  };

}
FlatListItemSeparator = () => {
return (
  <View style={{
     height: .5,
     width:"100%",
     backgroundColor:"rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
}}
/>
);
}

renderItem=(data)=>
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.list}>
<Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.name}</Text>
<Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.email}</Text>
<Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.company.name}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
render(){
 fetchdata()
 {
 if(this.state.loading){
  return( 
    <View style={styles.loader}> 
      <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0c9"/>
    </View>
)}}
return(
 <View style={styles.container}>
 <FlatList
    data= {this.state.dataSource}
    ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}
    renderItem= {item=> this.renderItem(item)}
    keyExtractor= {item=>item.id.toString()}
 />
</View>
)}
}
const parseString = require('react-native-xml2js').parseString;

    fetch('http://192.168.200.133/apptak_service/apptak.asmx/Get_Item_Master')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then((response) => {
            parseString(response, function (err, result) {
                console.log(response)
            });
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('fetch', err)
            this.fetchdata();
        })

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
   },
  loader:{
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
   },
  list:{
    paddingVertical: 4,
    margin: 5,
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
   }
});
```

The problem is that when the returned data is 1000 items and i try to display it on the app it causes immediately for the app to crash so i came up with this  idea just to just print two elements from the webservice to the console.Please help

Comment: Have you tried to paginate your elements based on the request or to lazy load and render the elements while the user scrolls?

Comment: @mnemosdev Thankyou for your suggestion  right now what i am trying to achieve is just print  two elements in the terminal/console any idea how do i achieve that?

Comment: Never call asynchronous methods in `render()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the state object you are using in FlatList, the **dataSource** element is missing. That is why your app is crashing. To add state update your state to this:

```
this.state = {
   loading: false,
   items:[],
   dataSource: []
  };
```

If you want to print only first two records you can just access them from response.

```
console.log(response[0], response[1])
```

OR

```
console.log(response.data[0], response.data[1])
```